# About MySql delete using keys

Tags: mysql, sql, join, key, inner-join

How to remove all the reminders belonging to the news created by Jack?

These are tables created by me with same data and now I want to fire SQL query for above requirement.

[image]

This is what I tried

```sql
DELETE FROM reminders
USING news
INNER JOIN reminders
WHERE CreatedBy = 'Jack'
      AND reminders.ReminderId = news.NewsId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the `USING` syntax in MySQL deletes to be a bit confusing -- because `USING` is already used syntactically as a replacement for `ON`.

Something like this should work:

```
DELETE r
    FROM reminders r JOIN
         news n
         USING (NewsId)
    WHERE n.CreatedBy = 'Jack';
```

Note that the join condition is on `NewsId` in *both* tables.